# What is an "assembly" in VS2010 C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

What is an Assembly in VS2010? Is it the series of tests (which could be, for example, codedUITests) run in a specific test list from Test List Editor? If it isn't what is an assembly and what is the word for the test list?

All this is because I'm trying to research the answer to my [main question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089025/how-do-i-impliment-classinitialize-classcleanup-in-my-codeduitest-in-msvs-2010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [.NET Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly) is the ultimate output of a build. It can be a Class Library (.DLL) or a program (.EXE).  Assemblies contain classes (and structs and enums).

Comment: So if I'm running a series of CodedUITests using Test List Editor, is the final test list an 'Assembly'?

Comment: No, a Test List is just that -- a Test List. The individual unit tests themselves (UI or otherwise) are compiled into a test assembly, which is the output of the test project. But the Test List is just metadata -- a list of unit test classes to run in a particular order (I believe it's stored in a file named *.vsmdi at the solution level.)

Answer (score 0):

when we compile any application in .net then it converts into assembly or exe.
I there is mail in application then it convert into EXE other wise it convert into assembly.
Its other name is portable executable file.
assembly has 4 parts
1:menifest
2:MSIL
3:metadata
4:Resources

Rajdeep

Comment: 'I there is mail in application' this part doesn't make sense. Did you want to say 'if there is a main() in sources'?